# is there anyway to provide a ics Calendar file that will automatically keep in sync with updates

Tags: c#, synchronization, icalendar

i see using [this calendar library in C#](http://www.ddaysoftware.com/Pages/Projects/DDay.iCal/) that i can programatically generate an ics file with a bunch of calendar events.

but I want a solution if i a person wants to subscribe to a calendar so when future events get added or deleted that that person gets updated.

When you subscribe to a ics file on a server from outlook, it looks like outlook just gets a snapshot based on this from the outlook help file:= (i assume its the same behavior as it i sent a calendar via email)

*Send a Calendar via E-mail   You can send any of the calendars you own to another person in an e-mail message. This is a type of Internet Calendar called a Calendar Snapshot. The calendar appears within the body of an e-mail message. However, an Office Outlook 2007 user who receives the Calendar Snapshot can choose to open the calendar as an Outlook calendar. Doing so can display the Calendar Snapshot and the current calendar in side-by-side mode or calendar overlay mode.*

is there any programmatic solution to allow a person to subscribe to a iCalendar file (or other format) that would always stay up to date with the latest changes over time?

Comment: If Outlook doesn't refresh ever what it read from an URL, that's really tough. About every client I know will reload remote calendars in certain intervals, something like 30 minutes per default.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz - so basically you are saying its the responsibility of the client app to simply poll the remote ics data and re sync

Comment: That's the way I know. (At least Mozilla Sunbird/Lightning and KDE whatsitsname do it that way.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Outlook *will* update based on a server-based .ics file.  Store the file on a web server somewhere (I have used a Wiki page successfully) and then use a webcal:// address instead of the http:// address.  Outlook should pick this up automatically.

This will generally refresh as part of the "Send/Receive" but can also be configured through "Account Settings...Internet Calendars".

I have done exactly what you are looking to do, same library and all.  The update worked a treat within a large organisation with many people subscribing to the calendar files.

This might help as well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_affronti/archive/2006/05/10/594986.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> it looks like outlook just gets a snapshot based on this from the outlook help file:= (i assume its the same behavior as it i sent a calendar via email)

I don't think this is a valid assumption. My company's firewall seems to be blocking things, so I can't test this completely, but the Subscription Options in Outlook does talk about updates.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for push notifications or something along those lines?

Most iCal .ics based calendars on the web expect to be used in a polling type fashion similar to RSS or ATOM in which a client will periodically check to see if any changes have been made and if so download the new content accordingly. My understanding is also that WebDAV enabled servers may have the ability to allow some clients to modify these .ics files directly as well however it is still the responsibility of the clients to poll and update their local snapshot of a calendar when subscribed to one.

I don't have much experience with the Outlook calendar's support for iCal but I use Google Calendar pretty extensively, the built in iPhone Calendar App, and I've also used the Sunbird Calendar application as well in the past and all of them work pretty reliably in showing me updates when I check them.